# Redux-Form uses index as key for field arrays, isin't that an anti pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have started using [Fields Array from redux-form](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/), and it uses the index which is a simple integer as keys. But isin't that wrong? I have been testing it out and don't have any issues but [read this article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) which says it could cause issues. So how come this does not become an issue here?

Answer (score 0):

**Redux-Form** although a great package, not trying to say it isn't, has grown to have many issues and anti-patterns. Just take a look at its name *Redux-Form*, and take a look at this [Redux FAQ about keeping form state in redux](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#should-i-put-form-state-or-other-ui-state-in-my-store) - it says it is not preferred to keep form state in redux! How about that?

Now let's talk about iterating with indexes and why it is bad. Since you've read the article in your question, I assume you already understand it - It's because it is bad at keeping a unique representation of items, especially if they get moved up and down, old and new. Now that does not mean that it should **always** be avoided. If you are good at handling indexes and positions, you do not need to worry about that. Redux-Form is not the only package doing this, Formik is as well.

To conclude, using indexes as field arrays is not ideal, you will always be safer with something like `uniqid()`. But it is not the end of the world either. Redux Form is a highly complex package, and they know how to handle their state, so we can assume they know how to handle their indexes as well.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that they handle the indexes internally well then.